# How do I get ISO to load in VirtualBox through Virtual Optical Disk

Tags: virtualbox, windows-7, iso

Everyone-

I just can't get my iso to load in VirtualBox and keep getting "FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted.  I'm running Ubuntu 17.

What I've made sure of:

1. Storage: ISO is mounted under "Controler: IDE.  Optical Drive: IDE Primary Master (have tried Primary/Secondary Master/Slave combos - nothing).
2. System: Boot Order: Optical, Hard Disk, and no others checked.
3. System: I have checked "Enable I/O APIC"

Another thing to note, I downloaded the Windows boot data from Dell and saved on USB stick.  I couldn't figure out how to use the USB stick to load Win7 in VirtualBox so now trying the ISO route.  I used 'dd' in terminal to burn the files to ISO.  I noticed the permissions on the ISO file are listed as root.  Could that be the issue?  Does the user I'm running have to be added?  If so, how do I switch that?

I can't wait to figure this out and start using Windows in VirtualBox.  Thank you so much for any help here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, nobody answered and in the few days following I figured it out.  My problem had all to do with the ISO.  I thought dd copied over all the contents on the USB but wasn't pulling some of the boot files for whatever reason.  I just searched again for an Win7 ISO and came across (https://www.pcsteps.com/45-download-windows-7-iso-legally-free-digital-river/).  I followed the steps to get the ISO, attached to my Controler IDE, and bam... Windows began installation.

VirtualBox was always functioning fine, it was just the dang ISO.  I learned a lot in the process!

For anyone hitting a roadblock and just can't get their Windows ISO to work, hopefully the URL above helps.

Good Luck!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is essential to add the relevant part of that link into your post. This post will become invalid once this link is no longer functioning.